# How to build EXISTS clause in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model where there are 3 entities:

```
User
Project
Contributor
```

A Project has a Owner (who is a User) and has multiple Contributors (who are Users). In my dashboard, I want to list a User's projects i.e. all Projects where the User is a Owner or a Contributor.

Finding owned projects using `Project.findAll({where: [owner: user]})` is trivial. How do I modify this to find out the Projects where the user is also a contributor? This would (in the database query) translate to a sub-query using EXISTS clause.

Answer (score 18):

In general you can use `exists` clause in `where` like this:

```
Project.findAll({
    where: {
         $and:[sequelize.literal('exists (select 1 from "someTable" where ...)']
    }
})
```

Comment: Worked but I had to change, instead `$and` I used `[Op.and]`, that change makes it work. Thank you.

Comment: what if I have  2 `exists` clause? the first clause would be overwrited.

Answer (score 8):

For example we define next associations:

```
Project.belongsToMany( User, {through: 'Contributor'} );
User.belongsToMany( Project, {through: 'Contributor'} );

Project.belongsTo( User, { as: 'Owner', foreignKey: 'owner'} );
```

If you want to find projects where the user is a contributor and the owner at the same time you can do it like this:

```
user.getProjects({ where: {owner: user.id} });
```

Answer (score 1):

not a Sequelize user here but reading the docs it looks like you can simply use the **$contains** operator in your *where* clause. Something like:

```
Project.findAll({
    where: {
        owner: user,
        contributors: {
            $contains: [user.id]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: $contains maps to PostgreSQL's '@>' operator for array types, and doesn't work for relationships between entities.