# Seqeulize query a table with multiple where values for same column?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize query that looks like

```
 const deliveriesToCancel = await Model.ShipperContract.findByPk(organizationId, {
include: [
  {
    model: Model.Order,
    as: organizationId,
    include: [
      {
        model: Model.Delivery,
        as: "deliveries",
         where: {
            state: {
                [Op.not]: "DELIVERED" || "CANCELED_BYL" || "CANCELED_BY_SHIPPER"
            }
        }
      },
    ],
  },
],
```

});

Is it possible to query on Delivery table with 3 possible choices for state column? or in this case, WHERE !== those 3 values?
How can I write taht in seqeulize?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the deliveries where "state" isn't any of "DELIVERED", "CANCELED_BYL", or "CANCELED_BY_SHIPPER", you can use:

```
where: {
   state: {
      [Op.notIn]: ["DELIVERED", "CANCELED_BYL", "CANCELED_BY_SHIPPER"]
   }
}
```

Note:
`WHERE NOT IN` can be slow. If your dataset is huge and your query is slow, consider looking into modifying it to an `exists`. [Docs](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-performance-of-the-NOT-IN-SQL-query-statement), [Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093481/how-to-build-exists-clause-in-sequelize)